# VS code と　IDLE　の編集方法の違いについて

Tags: python, python3, vscode, python-idle

初めて質問致します、プログラミングや当サイト未経験者ですので
文章等で、非礼な書き方や内容が有れば申し訳ありません。

質問内容：

プログラミング言語種類：python

サンプルプログラムで写経しております。
VS codeでコーディングしてるのですがサンプルコード自体がエラーが出てたので
記載ミスなのかなと思っていたのですが、IDLEで走らせると読み込みます。

VS CODE　と　IDLE　で読み込みの違いは有るのでしょうか？

抽象的で申し訳ありません、初心者ゆえ説明も難しいので
わかる範囲で、教示いただけたら嬉しいです。

Comment: タイトルに挨拶は含めないでください。タイトルは質問文の要約が望ましく、回答者や閲覧者がタイトルを見て質問内容をわかるようにしてください。質問は`編集`から修正可能です。

Comment: 「エラーが出た」だけではなく、具体的に「表示されたエラーの内容」を質問文に含めましょう（`何か`が起きたという事実しか分からないです）。また、可能であればサンプルコードも提示してもらうと回答が付きやすいと思います。

Answer (score 2):

この質問のようなエラーが発生する可能性が一番高いのは、VS Code の環境だと思われます。詳しくは、下のページをみてください。
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python#_environments

英語なので簡単に説明しておくと、VS Code の左下にあるステータスバーに現在の環境が表示されます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
もし、どのPythonも選択されていない場合は、「Select Python Environment」と表示されます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

どのPythonも選択されていない場合や選択されているPythonがIDLEで走らせる時に使っているPythonと異なる場合は、当然エラーが出ます。

その場合は、メニューの[view]->Comannd Paletteを選択して、次に`Python: Select Interpreter`を選択したら、Pythonの実行環境の一覧が表示されるのでその中から適当なものを選択します。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
なお、「ctrl+shift+P」をしなくても「現在の環境」や「Select Python Environment」の文字をクリックすることでPythonの実行環境の一覧が表示されるので、それで環境を変更することもできます。